# Quantity in stock in stock locations in Exact Online

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

Using the following query, I found that for items that have a stock location, there are multiple rows returned from the REST API StockLocations of Exact Online:

```
select spn.item_code_attr || '-' || spn.warehouse_code_attr || '-' || stn.code key 
,      itm.itemgroupcode
,      itm.itemgroupdescription
,      spn.item_code_attr
,      spn.item_description
,      spn.currentquantity
,      spn.planning_in
,      spn.planning_out
,      spn.currentquantity + spn.planning_in - spn.planning_out plannedquantity
,      -1 bestelniveau /* out of scope */
,      itm.costpricestandard costprijs
,      itm.costpricestandard * spn.currentquantity stockvalue
,      spn.warehouse_code_attr
,      stn.code locatie
,      itm.unitcode UOM
, itm.id
, whe.id
, sln.stock
, sln.itemid
, sln.warehouse
, stn.id
from   exactonlinexml..StockPositions spn
join   exactonlinerest..items itm
on     itm.code = spn.item_code_attr
and    itm.code = 'LE-10242'
and    itm.isstockitem = 1
join   exactonlinerest..warehouses whe
on     whe.code = spn.warehouse_code_attr
left 
outer
join   exactonlinerest..stocklocations sln
on     sln.itemid = itm.id
and    sln.stock != 0
and    sln.warehouse = whe.id
left
outer
join   storagelocations stn
on     stn.id        = sln.storagelocation
and    stn.warehouse = sln.warehouse
--
-- Filter out no stock nor planned.
--
where  ( spn.currentquantity !=0
         or     
         spn.planning_in != 0
         or     
         spn.planning_out != 0
       )
and    spn.item_code_attr = 'LE-10242'
order 
by     key
```

For example, for this item, there are 10 StockLocations. When I sum the field Stock, it returns the stock quantity found in StockPositions. However, it seems that every transaction creates an additional StockLocation entry.

I would expect StockLocation to contain per location in stock the total amount to be found there.

## EDIT

The StockLocations API is described in `https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/{division}/logistics/$metadata` as:

```
<EntityType Name="StockLocation">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="ItemID"/>
  </Key>
  <Property Name="ItemID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="Warehouse" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="true"/>
  <Property Name="WarehouseCode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
  <Property Name="WarehouseDescription" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
  <Property Name="Stock" Type="Edm.Double" Nullable="true"/>
  <Property Name="StorageLocation" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="true"/>
  <Property Name="StorageLocationCode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
  <Property Name="StorageLocationDescription" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
</EntityType>
```

Somehow it is not documented at https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResources.aspx

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Uhm, that [table doesn't exist in the API](https://developers.exactonline.com/#RestRefDocs.html%3FTocPath%3DExact%2520Online%2520REST%2520API%7C_____1). Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussed question on Hackathon with engineer. This is as the StockLocation API works; the naming does not optimally reflect the contents, but this is intended behaviour.

With a `select field, sum(stock) from stocklocations group by field`, you can get the right information.

To improve join performance, it is recommended to use an inline view for this such as `select ... from table1 join table2 ... join ( select field, sum(stock) from stocklocations group by field)`.